# Text File To HTML Tabular Format in Shell

Tags: html, shell, awk

I have command whose outout is as below:
I want its output to be mailed in tabular Html format.

```
Barcode , %Used , Retention , Pool , State 


000118L7, 36%, expired, UKOffices_Weekly , E 
000126L7, 2%, expired, UKOffices_Weekly , E 
000127L7, 3%, expired, UKOffices_Weekly , E 
000128L7, 50%, expired, UKOffices_Weekly , E
```

Expected output

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with provided samples only. In case your real data is different then you could still take this as a starting point.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  FS=", "
  print "<html>" ORS "<title>" ORS "Storage report" ORS\
  "</title>" ORS "<head>" ORS "<style>" ORS "table, th,\
 td {" ORS "  border: 1px solid black;" ORS "\
  border-collapse: collapse;" ORS "}" ORS "th {"\
 ORS "  background-color: #00ff00;" ORS "}" ORS\
 "</style>" ORS "</head>" "<body>" ORS "<table  border=" s1 "1" s1 ">"
}
FNR==1{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    printf("%s%s","<th>"$i"</th>",i==NF?ORS:OFS)
  }
  print "</tr>"
  next
}
{
  print "<tr>"
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    printf("%s%s","<td>"$i"</td>",i==NF?ORS:OFS)
  }
  print "</tr>"
}
END{
  print "</table>" ORS "</body>" ORS "<html>"
}
'  Input_file
```

Above code will generate following HTML code:

```
<html>
<title>
Storage report
</title>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
</style>
</head><body>
<table  border="1">
<tr>
<th>Barcode </th> <th>%Used </th> <th>Retention </th> <th>Pool</th> <th>State</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>000118L7</td> <td>36%</td> <td>expired</td> <td>UKOffices_Weekly </td> <td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>000126L7</td> <td>2%</td> <td>expired</td> <td>UKOffices_Weekly </td> <td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>000127L7</td> <td>3%</td> <td>expired</td> <td>UKOffices_Weekly </td> <td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>000128L7</td> <td>50%</td> <td>expired</td> <td>UKOffices_Weekly </td> <td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

[image]